# Prime to Prime Sequel

Tags: mathematics, primes

This question is inspired by the [Prime to Prime](/q/91841) puzzle.

The first 24 Prime Numbers are

> 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89

Using up to 4 prime numbers and the following mathematical operations, get all 24 primes.

> **+ - × /**

No other operators are allowed (note the added restrictions from the previous question).

### Other rules

- You cannot use same prime number more than once in any equation.
- You can use only prime numbers.
- You do not have to use all the 4 primes in every equation.
- You must use the same set of 4 primes in every equation. If you select say 2, 13, 17, 23 then they are the only primes that to appear in every equation to get the 24 primes.
- Concatenation is forbidden.
- Parentheses are permitted.

**Please refrain from posting partial solutions as there are many sets of primes which will not work.**

Comment: I will be really surprised if there is valid answer exists in this condition.

Comment: @Oray according to Peter Taylor's comment on the previous puzzle, there is one unique solution

Comment: @hexomino have you excluded ^ intentionally?

Comment: @DEEM Yes, ^ is excluded.

Comment: Is this computer-allowed?

Comment: Onto my 5th candidate set of primes, I just may end up spending like 8 hours on this lol

Comment: @athin I have decided to allow computers for this one, but if somebody comes up with a non-computer solution, that would be very interesting and impressive.

Comment: Are we allowed to use parentheses?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Yes, parentheses are allowed. I usually see this as a given but can make explicit in the question if wanted.

Comment: I only have one left to find, but I can't :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the answer:

> $2=2$
>
> $3=3$
>
> $5=2+3$
>
> $7=\frac{43-3}{2}-13$
>
> $11=43-2\cdot(13+3)$
>
> $13=13$
>
> $17=43-13\cdot2$
>
> $19=13+3\cdot2$
>
> $23=43-2\cdot(13-3)$
>
> $29=43-13-3+2$
>
> $31=43-13+3-2$
>
> $37=43-3\cdot2$
>
> $41=\frac{43+3\cdot13}{2}$
>
> $43=43$
>
> $47=2\cdot43-3\cdot13$
>
> $53=43+13-3$
>
> $59=43+13+3$
>
> $61=43+13+3+2$
>
> $67=2\cdot(43-3)-13$
>
> $71=\frac{3\cdot43+13}{2}$
>
> $73=2\cdot43-13$
>
> $79=2\cdot(43+3)-13$
>
> $83=2\cdot43-3$
>
> $89=2\cdot43+3$

Comment: Great work! As far as I can tell, there is only one other set that works.

Answer (score 2):

Computer confirms that the only other solution is:

> $$\begin{align*}2 &= 2 \\3 &= 3 \\5 &= (2 + 3) \\7 &= - ((3 - 17) / 2) \\11 &= (17 - (2 \cdot 3)) \\13 &= ((17 + 61) / (2 \cdot 3)) \\17 &= 17 \\19 &= (2 + 17) \\23 &= (17 + (2 \cdot 3)) \\29 &= - ((3 - 61) / 2) \\31 &= - (3 - (2 \cdot 17)) \\37 &= (3 + (2 \cdot 17)) \\41 &= (61 - (3 + 17)) \\43 &= ((2 - 3) - (17 - 61)) \\47 &= (61 + (3- 17)) \\53 &= (2 + (3 \cdot 17)) \\59 &= - (2 - 61) \\61 &= 61 \\67 &= (61 + (2 \cdot 3)) \\71 &= ((2 \cdot 61) - (3 \cdot 17)) \\73 &= - ((2 + 3) - (17 + 61)) \\79 &= - ((2 - 3) - (17 + 61)) \\83 &= ((2 + 3) + (17 + 61)) \\89 &= (61 - (2 \cdot (3 - 17)))\end{align*}$$

Comment: That's the same set as in Oray's answer.

Comment: Sorry, lemme get the other one

Comment: @hexomino done.

Comment: Yes, very good, this was the other set I had found, +1 (P.S. some of your expressions need a little adjustment as they seem to give the negative value, e.g, 7)

Comment: Whoops, I used `~` for negative signs...

Comment: Why not $61-2$? Others can similarly do without negation.

Comment: ^ Help me optimize my program? My program iterates through each ordered pair of numbers, and iterates through each operation, and iterates through possible negations in that order. Therefore, since $(2,61)$ comes before $(61,2)$, my program outputs $-(2-61)$.